# Powershell: Copy-Item not working when in ForEach loop

Tags: powershell

The script I am including below needs to accomplish the following tasks.  It needs to get a list of servers from AD, then iterate through each of those server names and grab the second to the newest folder in a directory, rename it, and copy it to another server.

The Copy-Item command is not working when I have it in the foreach loop, as written below:

```
#gathering server names
$serverList = (Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like 'Q0*00*'" -SearchBase "OU=MPOS,OU=Prod,OU=POS,DC=N,DC=NET").name | Sort-Object | Out-File C:\Temp\MPOS\MPOSServers.txt
$serverListPath = "C:\Temp\MPOS\MPOSServers.txt"

#Retrieve a list of MPOS Print servers from text file and set to $serverNames
$serverNames = Get-Content -Path $serverListPath

#Iterate through each of the server names
foreach ($serverName in $serverNames) {

$reportServer = "a03"

Get-ChildItem "\\$($serverName)\d$\MPosLogs\Device" | 
Where { $_.PSIsContainer } | 
Sort CreationTime -Descending | 
Select -Skip 1 |
Select -First 1 |
ForEach-Object {

    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ("$serverName" + "_" + $_.Name) -PassThru |
    Copy-Item -Destination "\\$($serverName)\c$\temp\MPOS\Logs"

    }

}
```

However, it works fine if I am testing it outside of the ForEach loop, as written below:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\$($serverName)\d$\MPosLogs\Device" | 
Where { $_.PSIsContainer } | 
Sort CreationTime -Descending | 
Select -Skip 1 |
Select -First 1 |
ForEach-Object {

    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ("$serverName" + "_" + $_.Name) -PassThru |
    Copy-Item -Destination "\\$($serverName)\c$\temp\MPOS\Logs"

}
```

Any ideas as to why it is not working in the full script?  I am not changing anything when I test it, I am just running the above commands without being in the ForEach loop.  It is completing the rest of the tasks, except for the folder copies.  The folder copy only works if I am testing it outside of the ForEach loop on a single server.

When I say "it doesn't work", there are no errors or anything like that.  It simply is not copying the folders.

Thank you!  :)
LG

Comment: lol I remember this code :) `$ServerListPath` points to a valid file right?  can you show the result of `write-host $servernames`? I suspect that there's some problem with how that array is being generated

Comment: @MikeGaruccio hello  :)  Yes I wanted to start a new thread for a new issue.  Write-Host $serverNames lists out all of the server names in this format:  Q0001001 Q0002001 Q0003001 - etc.

Comment: hmm all in one line?  what does `$serverNames.Count` show?

Comment: Comments have no line breaks, so the server list could be on separate lines...

Comment: ohh right forgot about that, and thinking more about it that would generate SOME kind of error due to an invalid servername on the GCI.. but I don't see anything else that could be broken with the loop @LilithGoddess can you add a `Write-Host $servername` inside your `Foreach` loop? want to make sure your actually entering the loop, if so we can add more logging until we figure out where its breaking.

Comment: You're renaming the file before you try and copy. Don't you need to copy the "new" item?

Comment: @MikeGaruccio sure!  I used a smaller test file for the list of server names, listing only two of them just to see if it was working.  It does in fact, write each server name to the console as it loops.  Hope that helps!

Comment: @Eris yes, that is correct!  I believe that is why I added the -PassThru parameter, according to MikeGaruccio (in another post we were working on)...Mike, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Also - the copy does work fine using the same code, if it is not in the context of the foreach loop...

Comment: yea the copy should be fine, it works due to `-PassThru` sending along the new file name to the next element of the pipeline.   I'm not seeing any problems with the way your loop is set up tho.  lets try rebuilding the pipeline one stage at a time and outputting the results, starting with just `Get-ChildItem "\\$($serverName)\d$\MPosLogs\Device"` and adding one element at a time from there and making sure the results always match what you expect at that stage, and letting us know what step breaks if not.  also It probably doesn't matter but what is `$reportserver` doing?

Comment: @MikeGaruccio well that is extremely embarrassing.  I think I have just been staring at this script for too long, and did not realize that I was not actually copying the folders to $reportServer - it's a good thing you asked!!!  It definitely matters.  All is well now, after changing the final $serverName to actually read $reportServer.  Thank you, and sorry for wasting your time...I appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

@MikeGaruccio well that is extremely embarrassing. I think I have just been staring at this script for too long, and did not realize that I was not actually copying the folders to $reportServer - it's a good thing you asked!!! It definitely matters. All is well now, after changing the final $serverName to actually read $reportServer. Thank you, and sorry for wasting your time...I appreciate your help a lot.