# foreach copy-item not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

My `Copy-Item` doesn't work when included in a `foreach` loop. 
Much like [Powershell: Copy-Item not working when in ForEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245894/powershell-copy-item-not-working-when-in-foreach-loop) 
Only my destination folder is not set the same as the originating folder which seemed to be the problem there.

This is the very basic function. My objective is to grab the latest log files from a directory containting log files for lots of stuff. I'm only interested in a few defined in $servers. A line in Servers.txt looks like this: \\clientname\d$\logdirectory\processlog\

When I `Set-Location` to a path in servers.txt and run `Get-ChildItem` it works as expected.
I also need to generate a new folder for each object in \Logs\ but one thing at a time.

```cs
$servers = @()
$servers = Get-Content c:\Test\Servers.txt

$destServer = @()
$destServer = ( "clientname")
$destinationFolder = "\\" + $destServer + "\d$\Logs\"

foreach ($serverpath in $servers) {
    Write-Host " Copying from $serverpath "
    Set-Location -literalpath $serverpath | 
        Get-ChildItem |
        Sort-Object -Descending LastWriteTime |
        Select -First 2 |
        Copy-Item -Destination $destinationFolder -Recurse -Force
}
```

Comment: `Set-Location` doesn't have any output, so piping to `Get-ChildItem` won't have any effect. Remove the `|` after `Set-Location`

Comment: ...Or just use `$serverpath` for `Get-ChildItem`, as there is no need to change the current working dir.

Comment: Right, I think I added it to get it as similar to the non-loop as possible since that worked.